# Two versions of Diffusion coefficient

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas, diffusion, gas, mean-free-path

I found two versions of the Diffusion coefficient, first:

$$D=\frac{\pi \lambda }{8}\overline{c}$$

Where $ \overline{c}$ ist the particles mean thermal velocity and $\lambda$ the particles mean free path.
(Found in W. C. Hinds, Aerosol Technology. Wiley Interscience (1999). S.156)

and second the version from my lecture (also found on wikipedia):

$$D=\frac{ \lambda}{3} \langle v\rangle$$

Where $\langle v\rangle$ is the particles mean thermal verlocity.

Hinds gives two more equations (S.154):

$$c_{\text{rms}}=\sqrt{\frac{3kT}{m}}$$

$$\overline{c}=\sqrt{\frac{8kT}{\pi m}}$$

With $c_{\text{rms}}$ being the root mean square velocity of a particle, $k$ being the Boltzmann-constant, $T$ being the temperature and $m$ the particles mass.
My first thought was that maybe there is a typo in the book or the lecture notes so I calculated

$$\frac{c_{\text{rms}}}{\overline{c}}=\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{8}}$$

which led to

$$\overline{c}=\sqrt{\frac{8}{3\pi}}c_{\text{rms}}$$

so I replaced $\overline{c}$ in

$$D=\frac{\pi \lambda }{8}\overline{c}$$

just to come to

$$D=\frac{\pi \lambda }{8}\sqrt{\frac{8}{3\pi}}c_{\text{rms}}$$

Which (set $\langle v\rangle=c_{\text{rms}}$, due to the potential typo) because of the square root isn't

$$D=\frac{ \lambda}{3} \langle v\rangle$$

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

So to start out, you're looking at the RMS and mean of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution; you can look them up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution), where they match Hinds' expressions.

In the two expressions you have, you see they'd cancel out were you to get rid of the square root. So, I believe $\lambda$ to be defined differently in your source material: In the one in Hinds, $\lambda = \bar{c}\tau$, whereas on the page on Wikipedia you found, I take it $\lambda = c_\text{rms}\tau$.